# Possible Performance issue with Azure query

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

I have this code:

```
IEnumerable<Users> allItems = await MobileService.GetTable<Users>().CreateQuery().ToEnumerableAsync();

foreach (var item in allItems) {
    if (item.Email.Equals(emailEntry.Text)) {
        emailIsValid = true;
    }
}
```

Which retrieves all items in my azure table and then I check if the email entered in the text field is valid (matches one in the azure table). The question is it seems to me that with the possibility of thousands of user logs in my table I don't know know if this method of email validation is feasible performance wise, if it isn't feasible what would be a better way to do this?

Comment: construct the query to do most of the heavy lifting on the server. apply a filter to reduce data over the wire.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Construct the query to do most of the heavy lifting on the server side. Apply a filter to reduce amount of data over the wire.

Something like this

```
var email = emailEntry.Text;
var query = await MobileService.GetTable<Users>()
                               .Where(item => item.Email == email)
                               .ToEnumerableAsync();

var emailIsValid = query.Any();
```

Unless there is a need to use all the user then no need to get all of them.